# Unable to ssh into EC2 instance. Operation timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

I configured a EC2 instance (logged in and successfully added dependencies) but I had a problem with the pem key and I was no able to connect to it anymore.

Then, I decided to backup and restore the content of the EC2 instance on a new server (Created a AMI image and generated a new pem key), but I faced the “Operation Timed Out” problem.

As troubleshooting, I started with checking the security groups and they were ok (allowing all incoming connections on TCP (SSH, HTTP)).
Finally, I checked the NACLs of the associated VPC. Still, the same problem arises.

For this reason, I decided to create a new server with the same security groups and I successfully logged in to the server.

Thus, I assume that the problem could be related to some internal dependency that overload the RAM of the whole instance or, more likely, to wrong access parameters (key/username of instance). AWS says to check the default user name for accessing the instance but since the AMI image is created ad-hoc I don't know what it is.

Other details:

The command I used for ssh:

```
ssh -i pathToKey ubuntu@IPMachine
```

I tried ubuntu, ec2-user and root as username and also to login using the public DNS rather the IP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that you use correct IP address? Also is the instance in a public or private subnet?

Comment: The IP is correct and it’s in a public subnet.  The weird thing is that if I create a new instance with a simple Ubuntu image and the same security groups it works perfectly. The issue arises when I restore from the custom AMI of the initial instance

Comment: Did you try using web-ssh clients available in AWS console for your instance?

Comment: yes, it didn’t work. it says “parameters are wrong or there are problems with connecting to the instance”